# LINQ - Speeding up query that has a join to a huge table

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, query-optimization

I have these two tables

```
ExpiredAccount                    Account
--------------                    ---------------
ExpiredAccountID                  AccountID
AccountID (fk)                    AccountName
...                               ...
```

Basically, I want to return a list of ExpiredAccounts displaying the AccountName in the result.

I currently do this using

```
var expiredAccounts = (from x in ExpiredAccount
                       join m in Account on x.AccountID equals m.AccountID
                       select m.AccountName).ToList()
```

This works fine. However, this takes too long.
There's not a lot of records in expiredAccounts (<200).
The Account table on the otherhand has over 300,000 records.

Is there anyway I could speed up my query, or alternatively, another way to do this more efficiently with or without using LINQ?

Comment: Is this linq to objects or is it an ORM?  If it's an ORM what is the query provider you're using?

Comment: Do you have any indexes applied (say, to the `AccountID` columns) on the underlying tables?

Comment: @Servy provider is `System.Data.SqlClient`
@mellamokb I'm not much of a DB guy, but it says PK_Account (clustered). I don't know if this helps.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where do `ExpiredAccount` and `Account` come from?  Are they local variables?  Can you show the code how they are populated?  It's possible for example that the way you've defined those variables causes the application to load both tables into memory, and apply the join in-memory, instead of sending a streamlined query to the backend.

Comment: @mellamokb Just regular code first approach: `public IDbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }` But yeah, adding a `virtual` property of the related table just like in the solution really did the trick. Load time was almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, assuming you are using Entity Framework, you don't need to be using the join at all.  You could simply do:

```
var expiredAccounts = (from x in ExpiredAccount
                       select x.Account.AccountName).ToList()
```

However, I don't think they will generate a different query plan on the database.  But my guess is that you don't have an index on AccountID in the Account table (although that seems unlikely).

One thing you can do is use ToTraceString (for example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/4a17b992-05ca-4e3b-9910-0018e7cc9c8c/) to get the SQL which is being run.  Then you can open SQL Management Studio and run that with the execution plan option turned on and it will show you what the execution plan was and what indexes need to be added to make it better.

Comment: This worked great after modifying the `ExpiredAccount` model to have a virtual `Account` property! The load times changes drastically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Contains` method:

```
var expiredAccounts = (from m in Account where ExpiredAccount.Select(x => x.AccountId)
                                                             .Contains(m.AccountId)
                       select m.AccountName).ToList()
```

It should generate `IN` clause in SQL query that will be performed agains database.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this and I don't think it would work without a join. `Unable to create a constant value of type 'ExpiredAccount'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.`